# Apply If function to FoldList

Tags: functions, function-construction

I have defined the following function:

```
cpdz[c0_, m_,s_, r_, t_, n_] := 
If[c0 > 0, c0*(m*c0\s - (m - 1)*Exp[r*t/n]), 
c0*Exp[r*t/n]]
```

for s I have a set of lists like {{0,1,2,3,4},{5,4,7,8,9}}. Now I want to apply this function to FoldList like this:

```
CushionListe = 
Map[FoldList[cpdz[#1, 2, #2, 0.01, 2, 720] &, 
1569.3 , SetofLists] /@ 
SetofLists]
```

my problem is now Mathematica doesn´t evaluate the If function. How can i apply the If function to my FoldList with my set of lists for s? Sry it must be something in the defintion of the Map or FoldList but i doen´t know what is wrong. My set of lists must stay like this because I need an output that is again a set of lists.

Hope someone can help. Thank you

Comment: What does `m*\s` mean (inside of the `If` statement)?

Comment: You are asking *Mathematica* to calculate whether a list is greater than `0`, this is a meaningless expression.

Comment: Also, the way you use it, the comparison `(*List*) > 0` doesn't mean anything.  It has to be a `List` on both sides.

Comment: Also, is the `C0` in the third line really supposed to be capitalized?

Comment: I edited it sry mistake. @QuantumDot yes i want to know how can I edit the If function so that mathematica use every single number of the List from my FoldList expression

Comment: `Thread[If[...]]` might be of help here. @QuantumDot `m*\s` is likely an artifact of copy-pasting mathematica code - linebreaks in the notebook, and such.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP doesn´t work (mathematica doesn´t calculate the If function) I think i have to change something in the Map/FoldList function but i doen´t know what and how.

Comment: It turns out a bit trickier and is quite dirty: `Thread[Thread /@ (If[{1, 2, 3, -5} > 0, "yes", "no"])]`. Run this code, see if that's something that works for you.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP the problem is I get the list for c0 from my FoldList function you know what i mean the If function is only for the computation that should stand behind the FoldList function

Comment: I'm afraid, at this point I don't know what you mean. It would be helpful if you could explain what the desired output is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42836/discussion-between-user41673-and-lllamnyp).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was due to a simple, but unobvious syntax mistake.

The intended behavior is given by

```
FoldList[cpdz[#1, 2, #2, 0.01, 2, 720] &, 1569.3 , #] & /@ SetofLists
```

Comment: I think you need another `&` between the `FoldList` and `/@`. `FoldList[cpdz[#1, 2, #2, 0.01, 2, 720] &, 1569.3 , #]& /@ SetofLists`

Comment: @JackLaVigne 13 minutes ago :)